# Demonstration of the uniquenes of a QL matrix factorisation

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

One of my teacher say to us that the QL decomposition is unique.
I am not convinced. How can I demonstrate the decomposition is unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) starting from the last vector of the matrix. Consider a matrix
$$A=\left [ \begin{array}{c|c|c|c} v_1  & v_2 & \ldots &v_n 
\end{array} \right ]$$
Applying Gram-Schmidt,

$$ \begin{array}  u u_n=v_n & e_{n}=\frac{u_n}{||u_n||} \\
u_{n-1}=v_{n-1}-(v_{n-1}\cdot e_n)e_n &e_{n-1}=\frac{u_{n-1}}{||u_{n-1}||} \\
\vdots & \vdots \\ u_{1}=v_1-(v_1\cdot e_2)e_2-\ldots -(v_{1}\cdot e_n)e_n & e_{1}=\frac{u_1}{||u_1||} \end{array}$$

Since $\langle v_n \rangle = \langle e_n\rangle, \ldots , \langle v_n,\ldots, v_1\rangle =\langle e_n,\ldots,e_1\rangle$ by construction, there exist real numbers $a_{(1j},\ldots a_{jj}$ for $1\le j \le n$ such that

$$v_{n-j}=\sum_{i=0}^{j}a_{((n-i),(n-j))}e_{n-i} \qquad 1\le j < n$$

We can suppose that these numbers are positive:  if $a_{ij}$ is negative, it suffices to exchange $u_j$ with $-u_j$ and consider $-a_{ij}$. Then,

$$\left [ \begin{array}{c|c|c|c} v_1  & v_2 & \ldots &v_n 
\end{array} \right ]=\left [ \begin{array}{c|c|c|c} e_1  & e_2 & \ldots &e_n 
\end{array} \right ]\begin{pmatrix} a_{1,1} & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\ a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & \ldots & 0\\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & 0 \\ a_{n,1} & a_{n,2} & \ldots & a_{n,n} \end{pmatrix}=QL$$

**If the matrix has full rank** all the entries of the matrix $L$ are strictly positive.

Now, suppose that
$$A=Q_1L_1= Q_2L_2$$
with $Q_1,Q_2$ orthogonal, $L_1,L_2$ lower triangular. Then
$$L_1^TL_1=L_1^TQ_1^TQ_1L_2=A^TA=L_2^TQ_2^TQ_2L_2=L_2^TL_2$$
Hence
$$(L_2^{-1})^TL_1^T=L_2L_1^{-1}$$
Since $L_1^{-1},L_2$ are lower triangular, $L_2^{-1},L_1^T$ are upper triangular. This implies that the matrix $L_2L_1^{-1}$ is diagonal (it's upper and lower triangular). The above identity shows that if $a_i$,$b_i$ are the diagonal values of $L_1,L_2$, then
$$\frac{a_i}{b_i}=\frac{b_i}{a_i}\implies a_i=b_i$$
because $a_i$, $b_i$ are positive. But then 
$$L_2L_1^{-1}=\mathbb{I} \implies L_2=L_1$$
Since $Q_1L_1=Q_2L_2$ and $L$ is invertible, $Q_1=Q_2$.

Comment: Is this a proof of uniqueness?

Comment: For the second proof, when the matrix has full rank, if we have L2= -L1 then we have Q2=-Q1. Can we still say that the matrix is unique?